# Trigger of a cloud function by a cloud storage bucket in different project

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I have a requirement where I need to trigger a cloud function which in turn triggers a data flow job once a file is placed in google cloud storage bucket of another project. Google documentation says its not possible, please see here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage

However, I tried doing this and my cloud function failed to deploy with below error. It says

[image]

Looks like this is a permission issue and if required permission are given , this will work.
Do I need to add and give owner permission to @appspot.gserviceaccount.com of the project(project A) from where I am trying to access the bucket of another project(Project B)

So if the above is true, In my project B IAM page, I will see 2 as below
@appspot.gserviceaccount.com OWNER
@appspot.gserviceaccount.com EDITOR

Any inputs on this is much appreciated.

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55726854/3082178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to catch event from other projects for now. But there is a workaround.

- In the project with the bucket, create a [PubSub notification on Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes)
- On the topic that you created, create a push subscription. Use the Cloud Functions URL, and secure the PubSub call (you can get inspiration from [there](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/pubsub-push#create-service-account). If you are stuck, let me know, I will take more time to describe this part)
- On the Cloud Functions grant the PubSub service account as cloudfunctions.invoker role

---

**EDIT 1**

The security part isn't so easy at the beginning. In your project B (where you have your Cloud Storage), you have created a PubSub topic. On this topic you can create a notification with a service account created in the project B. *Take care to well fill in the audience*

Then, you need to grant this "project B" service account as roles/cloudfunctions.invoker on the Cloud Function of the project A

```
# Create the service account
gcloud iam service-accounts create pubsub-push --project=<ProjectB>

#Create the push subscription
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create \
  --push-endpoint=https://<region>-<projectA>.cloudfunctions.net/<functionName> \
  --push-auth-service-account=pubsub-push@<projectB>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --push-auth-token-audience=https://<region>-<projectA>.cloudfunctions.net/<functionName> \
  --topic=<GCSNotifTopic> --project=<ProjectB>

#Grant the service account
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding --member=serviceAccount:pubsub-push@<ProjectB>.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker <FunctionName> --project=<projectA>
```

Last traps:

- The Cloud Functions in the project A haven't the same signature if it's an HTTP functions (callable by a pubsub push subscription) or a Background Function (callable by events, such as CLoud Storage event). You need to update this according to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#writing_http_helloworld-go)
- The PubSub message sent to the Cloud Functions is slightly different. Take care to update the input param accordingly.

Comment: thank you @guillaume blaquiere. I was able to create PubSub notification on cloud storage(project B) . I created a push subscription for this topic and provided push endpoint as  trigger url of the cloud function created in project A.  Hopefully I am right until this step. Please confirm. I have a SA which I am using to run cloud function in project A that is service-runner@<project A>.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Do I need to give this SA permission to invoke the service cloud function? Or a new one needs to be created? Kindly advise.

Comment: In continuation to my comment above, please also advise, if its the same SA I can use, as per documentation, I need to run this -> gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding SERVICE \
   --member=serviceAccount:SERVICE-ACCOUNT_NAME@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
   --role=roles/run.invoker , Here service name should be just cloudfunctions? I am not stuck as such but not sure if I am doing this right so that I can go ahead with this further.

Comment: I edited my answer with more guidance. Let me know if it's better

Comment: Thank you @guillaume blaquiere. You have made it so easy! I am yet to complete all steps as got into another issue related to service account. Working with the project owner to sought out the issues. Will let you know if I run into issues in any of the steps further. As always, I appreciate all your help and patience for looking into my issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Google documentation says its not possible

This is all you need to know.  It is not possible.  There are no workarounds, regardless of what sort of error messages you might see.

Comment: Thank you @doug stevenson. Just wanted to check if there was any work around based on the error that I got which was permission related.  Thank you again.

Comment: There may be some workarounds, but most likely they need some resources being deployed into the project, where those storage buckets are located.

Comment: I would guess it may become possible in the future... When the following issues/requests are resolved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62373846 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113360054 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534853 and so on...

Comment: I would not count on any of that happening in the near future.